# Constrained Optimization in R is worse than Manual

Tags: r, optimization

I am running constrained optimization in R. Code works and there are no errors. But optimized solution is worse off than what I can see manually! Optimization terminates with no error and 0 termination code. Yet, my solution has lower cost. Even when manual solution is fed as initial solution, program runs and doesn't complain about first solution being unfeasible (which it does in different case) and yet goes back to higher cost optimal solution.

Can you help what's happening? Below code runs and can directly be tested in R.

```
num.prod <- 4
cd.penalty <- 0.001
in.data <- data.frame(V1=c(70.22, 249.92, 241.55, 70.75), V2=c(185.04, 287.43, 240.07, 277.88))

# initial solution
temp <- max(in.data$V1, in.data$V2)
init.flow <- rep(round(temp,-floor(log10(temp))), (num.prod+1)^2)

# cost matrix
cost.mat <- matrix(0, nrow=num.prod+1, ncol=num.prod+1)
for (i in (num.prod/2+1):num.prod) {
    cost.mat[i, 1:num.prod/2] <- cd.penalty
    cost.mat[i, setdiff((num.prod/2+1):num.prod, i)] <- cd.penalty
    cost.mat[i, num.prod+1] <- cd.penalty
}


# constraint matrix
n <- num.prod + 1
cons.mat <- matrix(0, nrow=2*n+n*n, ncol=n*n)
for (i in 1:n) { # outflow
    cons.mat[i, ((i-1)*n+1):(i*n)] <- 1
}
for (i in 1:n) { # inflow
    cons.mat[i+n, seq(i, n*n, n)] <- 1
}
for (i in 1:(n*n)) { # var level
    cons.mat[i+2*n, i] <- 1
}

# constraints constants
balance <- c(c(round(in.data$V1,2), 0), c(round(in.data$V2,2), 0), rep(0, (num.prod+1)^2))

# objective function
flow.cost <- function(flow) {
    flow1 <- matrix(flow, nrow=num.prod+1, byrow=T)
    cost <- sum(flow1 * cost.mat) + sum(flow1 > 0.01)
    return(cost)
}

# optimized solution
result12 <- constrOptim(theta=init.flow, f=flow.cost, ui=cons.mat, ci=balance,
                        method="Nelder-Mead", outer.iterations=500, control=list(maxit=1000))

matrix(result12$par, nrow=num.prod+1, byrow=T) # optimize solution
result12$value # 17

# manual solution
mysol <- matrix(c(70.22291, rep(0,5), 249.92384, rep(0,5), 240.0733, 0, 1.47988, rep(0,3), 70.75244, 0, 114.81899, 37.50806, 0, 207.13116, 0), nrow=num.prod+1, byrow=T)
flow.cost(t(mysol)) # 8.00148
```

Comment: Your cost function isn't convex, nor continuous, and Nelder-Mead algorithm is known to get stuck on non-stationary points in the search space. Perhaps it will help if you can relax the discrete constraint `sum(flow1 > 0.001)` to a smooth L1 regularized constraint `const * sum(abs(flow1))` (the nearest approximation to L0 norm which is continuous + convex). I am afraid it'll be tricky to provide further insights in the problem.

Comment: Thanks. That worked...somewhat. Solution is still function of "const" of regularization, even though equation form would suggest that it shouldn't matter. Further, solution improved a lot but not still as good as what's visible ('manual solution').

I need to minimize number of non-zero variables, and that is not happening. optim seems to treat >=0 as >0, and minimum value taken in 0.01.

Comment: Would using the smoothed L0 norm, e.g. using https://github.com/bharbin/rsl0 perhaps work for you?

Answer (score 0):

With the following code, I have been able to achieve a value of 4 with the DEoptim algorithm.

```
library(DEoptim)

num.prod <- 4
cd.penalty <- 0.001
in.data <- data.frame(V1 = c(70.22, 249.92, 241.55, 70.75), V2 = c(185.04, 287.43, 240.07, 277.88))

temp <- max(in.data$V1, in.data$V2)
init.flow <- rep(round(temp, -floor(log10(temp))), (num.prod + 1) ^ 2)

cost.mat <- matrix(0, nrow = num.prod + 1, ncol = num.prod + 1)

for(i in (num.prod / 2 + 1) : num.prod)
{
  cost.mat[i, 1 : num.prod / 2] <- cd.penalty
  cost.mat[i, setdiff((num.prod / 2 + 1) : num.prod, i)] <- cd.penalty
  cost.mat[i, num.prod + 1] <- cd.penalty
}

# constraint matrix
n <- num.prod + 1
cons.mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 2 * n + n * n, ncol = n * n)

for(i in 1 : n)
{ 
  cons.mat[i, ((i - 1) * n + 1) : (i * n)] <- 1
}

for(i in 1 : n) 
{ 
  cons.mat[i + n, seq(i, n * n, n)] <- 1
}

for(i in 1 : (n * n))
{
  cons.mat[i + 2 * n, i] <- 1
}

balance <- c(c(round(in.data$V1,2), 0), c(round(in.data$V2,2), 0), rep(0, (num.prod + 1) ^ 2))

flow.cost <- function(flow, ui, ci)
{
  if(all(ui %*% flow - ci >= 0))
  {
    flow1 <- matrix(flow, nrow = num.prod + 1, byrow = TRUE)
    cost <- sum(flow1 * cost.mat) + sum(1 - exp(-pmax(flow1 - 0.01, 0)))
    
  }else
  {
    return(10 ^ 30)
  }
}

result12 <- DEoptim(fn = flow.cost, lower = rep(0, ncol(cons.mat)),
                    upper = rep(300, ncol(cons.mat)), control = list(itermax = 5000),
                    ui = cons.mat, ci = balance)

flow.cost_Init <- function(flow) 
{
  flow1 <- matrix(flow, nrow = num.prod + 1, byrow = TRUE)
  cost <- sum(flow1 * cost.mat) + sum(flow1 > 0.01)
  return(cost)
}

flow.cost_Init(flow = result12$optim$bestmem)
[1] 4
```

This is better than the manual solution of approximately 8.